# Formatting text with printf or printstring in C

Tags: c

I want to print text to a terminal program from a microcontroller, something like this:

```
printString("textline one here:            OK\n");
printString("textline two here that is longer:             OK\n");
printString("textline three here that is even  longer:             OK\n");
```

How do I make the text to always be in columns even if I decide to change the textline? To avoid that it looks something like this in the printout in the terminal program:

```
textline one here:             OK
textline two here that is longer:              OK
textline three here that is even  longer:              OK
```

and more like this (without having to add extra spaces in text and double check in the terminal program how it looks for every change I do to any text) :

```
textline one here:                             OK
textline two here that is longer:              OK
textline three here that is even  longer:      OK
```

Is it easier to use printf or printstring for this?

Comment: `printstring` is not a standard C function.

Comment: Use a fixed width.  `printf("%-80s%s\n", "text one line", "OK")`

Comment: The section here on format placeholders has some useful information about the flags you can use to format your string: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string

Comment: I'd suggest leaving a couple of spaces between the conversion specifications in `printf("%-75s   %s\n", message, status);` so that even if the message is longer than the specified length (75 here), you get separation between the string and the status.  Alternatively, tell `printf()` to truncate the message: `printf("%-75.75s   %s\n", message, status);`.  You could change the lengths dynamically; replace the `75` values with `*` and pass an `int` argument before the value: `printf("%-*.*s   %s\n", 75, 75, message, status);`.

Comment: Thank you all so much for your help!! really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than including the first part of the text directly in your `printf` format string, pass it as a parameter to the `%s` format specifier.  You can then add a field width to it to specify the minimum number of characters to print as well as the `-` flag to tell it to left-justify.

For example, this code:

```
printf("%-50s %s\n", "textline one here:", "OK");
printf("%-50s %s\n", "textline two here that is longer:", "OK");
printf("%-50s %s\n", "textline three here that is even  longer:","OK");
```

Prints:

```
textline one here:                                 OK
textline two here that is longer:                  OK
textline three here that is even  longer:          OK
```

Also, you could use `*` instead of an a explicit field width to pass it in as a parameter.  That way if you need to change the column width you only do it in one place:

```
int width = 50;
printf("%-*s %s\n", width, "textline one here:", "OK");
printf("%-*s %s\n", width, "textline two here that is longer:", "OK");
printf("%-*s %s\n", width, "textline three here that is even  longer:","OK");
```

Comment: Thank you all so much for your help!! really appreciate it.

Comment: @mannen Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.